# Is ColdFusion Scripted Linearly? Why this error?

Tags: coldfusion

I have received this error

```
Element CUSTOMERID is undefined in CLIENT. 
D:\Inetpub\wwwsitecom\wwwroot\rders.cfm:296
```

on a page that begins with the following code:

```
<cfif NOT CreateObject("component","User.User").IsLoggedIn()>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href='/index.cfm';
    </script>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>

<cfif NOT IsDefined("client.customerid")>
    <cfparam name="client.customerid" default="0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("We're sorry.");
    window.location.href="/logout.cfm";
    </script>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

and on line 296

```
<cfinvoke component="Account" method="getAccessInfo" returnvariable="getInfo">
  <cfinvokeargument name="customerid" value="#client.CustomerID#">
</cfinvoke>
```

The IsLoggedIn Function has this piece of code

```
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists(client,"customerid")>
  <cfset strIsLoggedIn = 0>
</cfif>
```

If ColdFusion processes scripts linearly, how would it have gotten to the undefined client.customerid on line 296 without processing the first parts of the page?

If ColdFusion does not process scripts linearly, how can I prevent this error?

Comment: might need to use your general debug skills to solve this.  CFDUMP is your friend.

Comment: Henry, thanks, there is a dump that is emailed on error.  It includes a listing of the client scope.  The entire client scope is empty.  There is nothing in client at all!  This is strange as well because there are references to other client variables that appear before line 296 that are just as subject to the error.

Comment: Can you try: <cfset getInfo = Account.getAccessInfo(customerid=client.CustomerID)> ? see if it works

Comment: I assume there's nothing between the top piece of code and line 296 that somehow changes the ApplicationName, right?

Comment: You might also try moving the `cfparam` out of -- and above -- the `not isdefined` conditional. That's sort of the point of `cfparam`. Then change your conditional to check for `client.customerid eq 0`. Maybe that combination is somehow monkeying with the client variable.

Comment: Ken, your assumption is correct.  Nothing changes the application name.  I like your idea of moving cfparam.  It has since been determined that our customers do not see the error but instead they are sent to the index or the logout page.  It is as though the abort is not honored, or the invoke begins out of sequence.

Comment: Ken, the only reason the client.customerid was paramed inside of the cfif was to prevent execution errors on the rest of the page.  As seen here, that is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would check that you aren't creating a variable somewhere (perhaps in an implicit scope in a `<cfoutput>` or `<cfloop>` tag) that's named `client`.  Since CF is a late-bound language, that can change the semantics, and references to `client.CustomerID` will be looking in your local `client` variable, not the `Client` scope.

Secondly, if you want to do a redirect, please, *please*, use `<cflocation>` instead of doing this crazy JavaScript redirect.  Remember that JavaScript is executed on the client side, and it is perfectly possible (and not even that uncommon) for browsers to have JavaScript disabled.  `<cflocation>` results in an HTTP 3xx response being sent, which will work correctly in any browser that implements HTTP, regardless of whether or not JavaScript is enabled.  It's also much more secure, since there's no chance of parts of the page being flushed to the client before the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have client variables set up correctly in cfide and check that they are enabled in your Application.cfc file.